# Creating a stored procedure to insert specific data into 1-2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, freetext

I have two tables,

```
Idea(Idea_ID int primary key, Idea_name varchar(30))
```

And

```
Keyword(Idea_ID int, Keyword varchar(15), weight numeric(1,0))
```

I am looking to create a stored procedure which inserts data into the `Idea` and/or the `Keyword` table. The format of the input would ideally be `(Idea_name, K1,W1,K2,W2,K3,W3...etc)` with Ks being Keywords and Ws being the weight.

I would like it so that if the Idea name can't be found in the `Idea` table, a new Idea name is first inserted into the `Idea` table, and then the other data inserted into the `Keyword` table. Is it also possible to have the stored procedure check the input pattern to make sure it has the correct formatting and the correct data types, showing a string if there is an issue?

Thanks in advance for the help, I am quite new to stored procedures and the MSSQL freetext search engine! Are there any other relevant tags I could include?

Cheers

Comment: Schools must be back in session.

Comment: @ sam yi, Sure is mate! Very constructive, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use a comma separated list, there are much better ways of doing this, in my opinion there is no place for delimited strings in SQL.

If you are using SQL-Server 2008 or later then you can use table valued parameters to pass your keywords to the store procedure:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.KeyWords AS TABLE (Keyword VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Weight NUMERIC(1, 0));
```

Your procedure would then be something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SaveIdea @IdeaName VARCHAR(30), @Keywords dbo.KeyWords READONLY
AS
    DECLARE @IdeaID INT = ( SELECT  TOP 1 Idea_ID 
                            FROM    dbo.Idea 
                            WHERE   Idea_Name = @IdeaName
                        );

    IF @IdeaID IS NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT dbo.Idea (Idea_Name) VALUES (@IdeaName);
            SET @IdeaID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
        END
    MERGE dbo.KeyWords t
    USING @Keywords s
        ON t.Idea_ID = @IdeaID
        AND t.Keyword = s.Keyword
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Idea_ID, KeyWord, Weight)
        VALUES (@IdeaID, s.Keyword, s.Weight)
    WHEN MATCHED AND t.Weight != s.Weight THEN UPDATE
        SET Weight = s.Weight
    OUTPUT $Action, inserted.*;

GO
```

The first check is to see if an idea exists with that name, if it does no new row is inserted, otherwise a new idea is added. It then Merges the keywords. If they already exist for that idea they are not added, but if the weight is different this is updated. If they keyword doesn't exist it is inserted.

Then to use this you can use something like:

```
DECLARE @Keywords dbo.KeyWords;

INSERT @Keywords (Keyword, Weight)
VALUES
    ('Test 1', 1),
    ('Test 2', 2),
    ('Test 3', 3),
    ('Test 4', 5),
    ('Test 5', 4);

EXECUTE dbo.SaveIdea 'Test Idea', @Keywords;

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Idea;

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Keywords;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/336e6/1)**

Although this is more practical to call from your application layer.